# How can I find out if the event is being catched in the parent component

Tags: vue.js

I have a generic component(Used at multiple places), which emits a event on action. Example:

```
onClick(value) {
   this.$emit('on-click', value); //But I want to do this only if there a listener on on-click event

   // Else
   this.defaultAction(); // Or if there is no listener in the parent component then do some default action.
}
```

I can always pass another prop for the check, but can this be done without that?

Comment: you dont think this is redundant? this will call listeners registered in an array, so to check if there is a listener and then call doubles the work needed

Comment: So you think adding a prop for my use case will be a better option? Isn't there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.$listeners['on-click']`, this can be used to check if there is a adjacent listener for the event.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `vm.$listeners` (`vm` is the component instance) property to check for the presence of event handler. See the [Vue.js API docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners) for more details. (Also, this is how it is done in JSX way of doing things both in Vue JSX and React JSX.)

> But note that this is a way brittle way to think about it in Vue.js.

The problem is not if you should add extra prop to indicate presence of listener or not. The problem is the abstraction. Sometimes, you are making **parent** do the work and sometimes **child** component. In short, your workflow is fragmented and the smell of UI not being a good function of state is evident.

Either do both if/else scenarios in parent (i.e. same level of abstraction) and make it mandatory to provide listener always or do it in child component always.

Comment: That's right, But In my case the child component is very generic and I dont want to change all other components using it. And only few components need to do some specific action depending on the event.

Comment: @Neha In that case, introduce HOC - Higher order component. A third component over your child component which encapsulate this behavior. So Parent -> HoCChild -> Child. This cross-cutting logic neither your child nor main parent should contain.